# Open URL from WebView in browser

Tags: android, url, android-webview, android-browser

I need to open the URL in default browser of the phone (not in the application's `WebView`). Below is my code, but it launches the URL in `WebView`.

How can I open the URL in the default browser?

**Activity2.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

      webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
      openURL();
    }

    /** Opens the URL in a browser */
    private void openURL() {
      webview.loadUrl("http://www.XX.org");
      webview.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of webview, If you're planning url to open in broswer then go with the below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.XX.org"));
startActivity(i);
```

If you want to open facebook app from your code:

```
try {       
    String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Comment: I have button facebook, it's possible when user click on button facebook, the page open in facebook application?

Comment: do you want to open facebook app, onclick of button?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have ImageButton (Facebook) & onClick the page open in the facebook app (not in browser)

Comment: Thanks you Harsha - Your code open just the facebook application but not the page directly.
try {       
    String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/MYPAGE_HERE";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
}